# Material Table column fixed width

Tags: css, angular-material2

I have an Angular Material table, and I'd like to apply a fixed width of `100px` to the first column.

[image]

I tried using:

```
.mat-column-select {
  flex: 0 0 100px !important;
}
```

with no effect.

What am I missing?

Edit:
Ok... I'm not a CSS guy. Just adding `width: 100px` did the trick. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congratulations for finding the solution on your own.

The table is a `<table>` element. Which is not default `display: flex`.
`flex: 0 0 100px` will only work if the parent element is a flex box.

Since `<td>` is displayed as `table-cell`. Thats why `width: 100px` should do the work.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Henry!